# How to separate data in CDATA

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

When I use this code throughout my document:

```
<?php echo $dataField->categoryName; ?>
```

with the namespace `$dataField` defined earlier as:

```
<?php $feed = file_get_contents("http://utah.technologypublisher.com/RssDataFeed.aspx?CaseId=u-4716"); $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed); foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry){$namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true); $dataField = $entry >children($namespaces['dataField']);} ?>
```

I get `Diagnostics| Engineering & Manufacturing` as the output.

Whenever a category is singular that works just fine (there won't be a "|") but I need to separate the data so that "Diagnostics" and "Engineering & Manufacturing" appear on their own line. Sometimes there may be as many as four categories and I need a method for extracting them (there are over 30 categories). I can do this:

```
<?php if (strpos($dataField->categoryName[0], '|') !== FALSE) print_r(explode('|', $dataField->categoryName[0], 4)); ?>
```

But this results in:

```
Array ( [0] => Diagnostics [1] => Engineering & Manufacturing )
```

I don't want them printed into an array. Whenever the data is separated by "|" I need each category on its own line. Any ideas on how to do this? It's probably simple.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't store pipe separated data in a CDATA block. Use XML elements, that is why they exist.

Comment: See above, please normalise your response.

Comment: I have no control over the feed. I'm not the one storing separated data in a CDATA block. I think I figured it out though: <?php
if (strpos($dataField->categoryName[0], '|') !== FALSE)
   { $array=(explode('|', $dataField->categoryName[0], 4));
 echo '<pre>'; echo $array[0]; echo '</pre>'; 
 echo '<pre>'; echo $array[1]; echo '</pre>';
 echo '<pre>'; echo $array[2]; echo '</pre>';
 echo '<pre>'; echo $array[3]; echo '</pre>';
 }
else {
    echo $dataField->categoryName; 
 }
?>